# Keras: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a neural network with keras and tensorfrolw as backend. it has 3 inputs from 0 to 9 and 3 outputs from 0 to 9. The data is served in a numpy array lie this: [ ['1' '4' '0'] 
 ['6' '2' '1'] ...].

I am new to deep learning and this is one of my first neural networks so i am lost and have no idea what is causing this error.

I am aware that i probably need to change the optimizer, loss, metrics and probably more attributes, if anyone has any insights on that please share.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(3, input_shape=(3, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(9, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(9, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="relu")
])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(training_input, training_output, epochs=5)
```

When i run this program i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/---/---/---/---/---/---/---/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    keras.layers.Flatten(3, input_shape=(3, 3)),
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 571, in __init__
    self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 191, in normalize_data_format
    data_format = value.lower()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower' \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) for using `Flatten()` layer. You are misusing the `Flatten`. I suggest you to do the reshaping of your data before your model and feed forward into the model.

Comment: Thanks dude. I should have written `keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=(3,)),`

Comment: Hope your problem resolves. Seems like your optimizers, loss or metrics is not problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I had provided an argument to the flatten layer when I shouldn't have. Busted:

```py
import tensorflow.keras.layers as l

h = i = l.Input(shape=(10, 5))
h = l.Flatten(50)(h) # don't do this!
o = l.Dense(50)(h)
model = keras.Model(inputs=i, outputs=o)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

With no argument specified the model compiles:

```py
import tensorflow.keras.layers as l

h = i = l.Input(shape=(10, 5))
h = l.Flatten()(h) # do this!
o = l.Dense(50)(h)
model = keras.Model(inputs=i, outputs=o)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```